# Backup-GPO error

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to backup all the GPOs on my Domain Controller.
The Domain Controller is running Server 2012 Standard Edition. Furthermore; both the Forest and the Domain Functional level are on 2012. When I use the command

```
Backup-GPO -All -Path $env:StaticPath\$(Get-Date -format d)
```

I get the following result:

```
Backup-GPO : The specified server cannot perform the requested operation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007003A)
At line:1 char:1
+ Backup-GPO -All -Path C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Backup-GPO], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Commands.BackupGpoComm 
   and
```

The same thing happens when I use a less exotic path. I found a link on TechNet regarding this issue but it did not contain a final solution. Also, upgrading the schema is no use as it is on 2012 already.

> Link:
>   http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/1efa4d27-858e-4495-b1ea-9202eeb24cc3/backing-up-gpos-with-server-2012?forum=winserverGP

I am running Powershell 3.0.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that adding the `-Domain` and the `-Server` switches to the command fixed the issue. Rather strange as the official documentation states them as optional. (As seen in the provided examples right here:

> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461052.aspx